# select поля jsonb postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql, select, jsonb

есть колонка типа jsonb, в которой хранится json вида:

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      "number": "3135/2016",
      "case_id": 5553767,
      "user": "guest"
    }
  ]
}
```

Как написать запрос, который бы отображал значения поля data.user ?

Answer (score 0):

`#>{data,0,user}` в простом случае https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/functions-json.html

Вложенным селектом можно пройти в общем случае

```
select user from jsonb_populate_recordset(jscol->'data')
```